# Get the total number of elements (iterations) in an XSLT for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I normally use jquery templates for this sort of thing but I inherited an XSLT file I need to update but I can't find a way to get the total number of elements (iterations) for a specific template call.

With jquery templates I'd do something like this and it would give me total number of assets that I'm looping through.

```
<span id="${spnID}">
    ${GroupName} (${Assets.length})
</span>
```

This would return me "Product x (5)" if there were five elements in the loop.

It seems simple but I can't seem to find a way to do the same thing with XSLT. Something like this, I think:

```
<span id="{$SpnId}">
    <xsl:value-of select="$GroupName"/> (<xsl:value-of select="$total-number-of-elements"/>)
</span>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Could you provide input XML?

Comment: Maybe the XPath [count function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256103.aspx) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're looping over some `$set` then output `count($set)` to get the total number of items to be iterated. For example, try this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="set" select="/table/row" />
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="count($set)" />
        <xsl:for-each select="$set">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), ' of ', $count, '&#xa;')" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Against this input:

```
<table>
    <row id="1" />
    <row id="2" />
    <row id="3" />
    <row id="4" />
    <row id="5" />
    <row id="6" />
</table>
```

Output:

```
1 of 6
2 of 6
3 of 6
4 of 6
5 of 6
6 of 6
```

Note that we're looping over the nodes selected by `/table/row` and outputting `count(/table/row)` to get the number of iterations.

Answer (score 3):

Wayne's answer works, and may be necessary in certain circumstances, when there are other requirements that must be met. But, if you've got a simple situation, you can do it more efficiently by using the Last() function. As soon as the for-each is processed, Last() contains the upper bound, or count, of the set.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/table/row">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), ' of ', last(), '&#xa;')" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Run against the same XML, the output is identical to Wayne's result.

```
1 of 6
2 of 6
3 of 6
4 of 6
5 of 6
6 of 6
```